# the result of calculated new column is not right

Tags: spotfire

There is a table of 12 columns. I would like to add an extra column, where each entry stores the average value of the corresponding row across those 12 columns. I use the feature "Calculated new column" to fulfill this task. After getting the result,  I noticed that the average value was returned as zero when one of the 12 columns has zero value on that specific row. For other rows, the calculation is just OK if none of the entries in those 12 columns is zero. I attached the screenshot of resulting table and the calculation procedure in the data table properties for your reference. Would you like to let me know the possible reason?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> average value was returned as zero when one of the 12 columns has zero

Actually you don't have zero values, but null values, which is different! Use `SN()` function to manage null values (need to use for all the columns)!